# How to use jquery in a function

Tags: javascript

So I want to hide an input in a function. Here's what I already have:

```js
function doGetWord() {
  var word = F.gword.value;
  var wLength = word.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < wLength; i++) {
    document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.cclick").click(function() {
      $("input.cword").hide();
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="F">
  <input type="text" name="gword" class="cword">
  <!--<input type="text" name="t" class="in2">-->
  <input type="button" name="b" value="do" onclick="doGetWord()" class="cclick">
  <div id="dword"></div>
</form>
```

But it doesn't seem to hide it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After double-clicking the "do"-button, your code snippet worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it doesn't seem to hide it.

You are binding a `document.ready` event inside a function, much after this event has been fired already. So these lines are unlikely to be reached

```
  $("input.cclick").click(function(){
        $("input.cword").hide();
  });
```

Simply put this

```
$("input.cword").hide();
```

without wrapping it in `document.ready` and `click` event

```
function doGetWord(){
    var word = F.gword.value;
    var wLength = word.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
        document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "  
    }
    $("input.cword").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost valid you've just to remove the inline event `onclick="doGetWord()"` since you attach it already form the JS side and call you function on click, then adjust the braces to separate the ready function form the `doGetWord` function, like :

```js
function doGetWord() {
  var word = F.gword.value;
  var wLength = word.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < wLength; i++) {
    document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "
  }

  $("input.cword").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.cclick").on('click', doGetWord);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="F">
  <input type="text" name="gword" class="cword">
  <!--<input type="text" name="t" class="in2">-->
  <input type="button" name="b" value="do" class="cclick">
  <div id="dword"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I copied your code, but it doesn't seem to work in mine?

Comment: Make sure that you haven't missed something and clear the cache too and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated code

```js
function doGetWord(){
    var word = F.gword.value;
    var wLength = word.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
        document.getElementById("cword").innerHTML += "_ "  
    }  
}

$("input.cclick").click(function(){
          $("input.cword").hide();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="F">
        <input type="text" name="gword" class="cword">
        <!--<input type="text" name="t" class="in2">-->
        <input type="button" name="b" value="do" onclick="doGetWord()" class="cclick">
        <div id="dword"></div>
    </form>
```